# Read JSON response with PHP

Tags: php, json

I've found similar questions, but none quite match my structure.  I've never worked with JSON so I'm unclear how parsing it works.

All I am trying to do is echo out a JSON response from a url, and manipulate the response as variables.  The structure is:

```
{"results":{"books":{"2014-05-13":[{"book":{"book_date":"2014-05-13","book_publisher":"Some Publisher","book_id":"123","book_author":"Some Author" etc etc etc
```

I'd like to be able to echo out and store each books date, publisher, id, author, into variables.

What I've been using causes the error: Invalid argument supplied for `foreach`()

```
$api_url = 'myurl/books.json';
$json = file_get_contents($api_url);
$json2 = json_decode($json, true);

foreach($json2->book as $book)
{
    echo $book->date;
    echo $book->publisher;
    echo $book->id;
    echo $book->date;
    echo $book->author;
}
```

Comment: foreach($json2['results']['books'] as $book){

Comment: Failing the above, please edit your question with the result of  var_dump($json2);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$json2 = json_decode($json,true);
```

will create an associative array

So you cant iterate it as object the way you are doing now.

You should get an array something as below

```
[results] => Array
        (
            [books] => Array
                (
                    [2014-05-13] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Array
                                (
                                    [book] => Array
                                        (
                                            [book_date] => 2014-05-13
                                            [book_publisher] => Some Publisher
                                            [book_id] => 123
                                            [book_author] => Some Author
                                        )

                                )

                        )

                )

        )
```

)

So you need to use array index to loop through the data.

Comment: Yes the var_dump shows this is how it is structured, but I'm still unclear how to read the information.  Can it be done with foreach?

Comment: Yes. You will probably have to use multiple loops though unless you always know the date component in advance. `foreach($json2['results'] as $result) { foreach ($result as $books) { foreach ($books as $date) { foreach ($date as $bookArray) { echo $bookArray['book']['book_date']; } } } }`

Comment: This works perfectly.  I went ahead and marked the answer as correct.  Thanks so much!